# IE9 randomly blocks the cursor from moving up a row in text boxes on wikis

Tags: internet-explorer-9, mediawiki, text-cursor

Ever since "upgrading" to IE9, I've been having a super-annoying and very inconsistent problem. While editing wikis, every now and then, I can't move the cursor to the previous row. Pressing the up arrow key simply doesn't do anything. Even weirder, moving the cursor to the beginning of the line and pressing the left arrow key causes the cursor to, instead of moving to the end of the previous line, move to the end of the current line. Moving down any number of lines and then moving back up doesn't remove the invisible wall; sometimes in fact it moves the wall to a lower line.

The only way to get around the problem is to click above the invisible wall, which correctly repositions the cursor. The problem then totally vanishes; the cursor is free to move around the entire text box with no problems, until it randomly gets caught up again somewhere else at an undefined later time. The only pattern I can make out is that it seems to happen more often when the cursor is near wikisyntax (`[[`, `]]`, `|-`, `==`, and so on). I cannot reproduce the problem intentionally, and I have yet to see it occur on any non-wikis - I have no way of knowing if this is a MediaWiki bug or simply due to different cursor habits causing the problem to never surface elsewhere.

Comment: Mainly because I hate change more than the average human. Partly because I can't stand FF's and Chrome's fullscreen modes.

Comment: FWIW, I've seen this problem on non-wiki sites, for instance on some forums (mostly using vBulletin software). It mostly seems to happen when there's a lot of text in the textbox. Another possible factor is if the textbox is some sort of Javascript-enhanced rich-text editor, rather than a plain HTML textarea. Haven't found a solution yet, though.

Comment: I've reported this issue as a bug with MSFT: http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/771031/cursor-up-sometimes-stops-working-correctly-in-multiline-text-boxes-possibly-with-javascript-enhancements. If someone has a reliable way of reproducing the issues (or can name a site where it can sometimes be reproduced), please leave a comment with the bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Is Caret Browsing on? That might cause undesirable cursor movement. You may also want to try Compatibility View, which may change the cursor behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Trying checking your zoom options. Whenever my zoom isn't 100% (which is the normal size) I experience behavior similar to what you describe.

> On the **View** menu, point to **Zoom**, and then select a different level.